# Проверка e-mail на валидацию

Tags: javascript, email, валидация

Пытаюсь совладать с валидацией. Нужно чтобы при не валидном e-mail окно для ввода подсвечивалось красным, при валидном - зеленым. Вроде логику правильную прописала, как мне кажется, и ошибка заключается в какой-то мелочи. Но эту мелочь не могу найти и поправить. Буду благодарна если тыкнете носом в ошибочку))

```js
const emailChecker = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;
const emailField = document.querySelector('#e-mail');

function isEmailValid(value) {
  return emailChecker.test(value);
}

function onInput() {
  if (isEmailValid(emailField.value)) {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'green';
  } else {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'red';
  }
}

emailField.addEventListener('#e-mail', onInput);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  max-height: 769px;
  background-color: #1B2473;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .body {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  height: 412px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 82px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    width: 728px;
    height: 697px;
  }
}

.form__preheader {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__preheader {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.form__header {
  width: 115px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__header {
    width: 138px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.form__field {
  width: 509px;
  height: 49px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__field {
    width: 638px;
    height: 49px;
  }
}

.form__star {
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  color: #787878;
}

.form__pc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form__box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__box {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.form__text {
  width: 278px;
  height: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__text {
    width: 358px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.form__send {
  width: 180px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #1A226B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__send {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form">

    <h1 class="form__header">Вход</h1>
    <p class="form__preheader">E-mail</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail">
    <p class="form__preheader">Пароль</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" placeholder="Введите пароль">

    <div class="form__pc">
      <input class="form__box" type="checkbox" id="box">
      <label for="box" class="form__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту
          </label>
    </div>

    <button class="form__send">
          Войти
      </button>

    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: В `addEventListener()` что это за ивент такой `'#e-mail'`?

Comment: `input type="email"` худо-бедно уже есть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще функция [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) первым аргументом принимает не **ID элемента**, а **тип** некоторого обрабатываемого события [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type). Полагаю, в Вашем случае сойдёт, например, [`keyup`](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events) (хотя `keydown` тоже сгодится как вариант).

```js
const emailChecker = /^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+\.)+[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]{2,})$/iu;
const emailField = document.querySelector('#e-mail');

function isEmailValid(value) {
  return emailChecker.test(value);
}

function onInput() {
  if (isEmailValid(emailField.value)) {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'green';
  } else {
    emailField.style.borderColor = 'red';
  }
}

emailField.addEventListener('keyup', onInput);  // #e-mail => keyup
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 1440px;
  max-height: 769px;
  background-color: #1B2473;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .body {
    max-width: 768px;
  }
}

.form {
  width: 600px;
  height: 412px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 82px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .form {
    width: 728px;
    height: 697px;
  }
}

.form__preheader {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__preheader {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.form__header {
  width: 115px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__header {
    width: 138px;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.form__field {
  width: 509px;
  height: 49px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 36px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__field {
    width: 638px;
    height: 49px;
  }
}

.form__star {
  width: 7px;
  height: 12px;
  color: #787878;
}

.form__pc {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form__box {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__box {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}

.form__text {
  width: 278px;
  height: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #787878;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__text {
    width: 358px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.form__send {
  width: 180px;
  height: 52px;
  background-color: #1A226B;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 26px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .form__send {
    width: 220px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form">

    <h1 class="form__header">Вход</h1>
    <p class="form__preheader">E-mail</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" id="e-mail" placeholder="Введите e-mail">
    <p class="form__preheader">Пароль</p>
    <input class="form__field" type="text" placeholder="Введите пароль">

    <div class="form__pc">
      <input class="form__box" type="checkbox" id="box">
      <label for="box" class="form__text">Я согласен получать обновления на почту
          </label>
    </div>

    <button class="form__send">
          Войти
      </button>

    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: большое спасибо за объяснение!